# SQL - Order by hierarchy

Tags: sql

I have a table with about 500M rows and I needed to order that table by parent and then its child. Each parent has only one child. I also needed to count the rows for each product that has this parent and child relationship.

The IDs are randomly generated. So it's not possible to just order by them.

An example table would be something like this:

| Id | Parent | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1aa | null | Product A |
| a2ba | null | Product B |
| bx2a | a1aa | Product A |
| cx2a | a3ba | Product B |
| aa2p | bx2a | Product A |
| zzba | aa2p | Product A |

The expect result would be this

| Id | Parent | Product | Row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1aa | null | Product A | 1 |
| bx2a | a1aa | Product A | 2 |
| aa2p | bx2a | Product A | 3 |
| zzba | aa2p | Product A | 4 |
| a2ba | null | Product B | 1 |
| cx2a | a3ba | Product B | 2 |

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Honestly, I have no idea where to begin in this case.

I can use `row_number over partition by`, however, I have no idea how to order by parent and child inside the partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most RDBMS's the correct approach is a Recursive CTE. The dialect differs slightly with different RDBMSs but they are fairly similar. The important part is that you want to capture the depth of the hierarchy as you traverse it from the top down.

The recursive CTE is made up of two SELECT statements unioned together. The top SELECT seeds the iterations. It's the starting point from which you iterate. So in it we will select all records with a NULL parent.

The bottom SELECT statement will refer back to the CTE in which it's contained and will join to your table. It establishes the relationship between parent and child, and it's the query upon which the database will iterate until the join fails.

```
WITH RECURSIVE rcte AS
(
     --seed the iteration by only choose null parent records
     SELECT id, parent, product, 0 as depth
     FROM yourtable
     WHERE parent IS NULL

     UNION ALL

     --iterative portion
     --including product in the join criteria
     -- since it looks like your hierarchy is 
     -- specific to the distinct product. 
     SELECT yt.id, yt.parent, yt.product, depth + 1
     FROM rcte
         INNER JOIN yourtable yt
             ON rcte.id = yt.parent --join to establish hierarchy
             AND rcte.product = yt.product 
)
--Now select from the CTE
SELECT id, parent, product, depth as row
FROM rcte
ORDER BY product, depth;
```

Like I said, the syntax may differ depending on your RDBMS. Read up in your RDBMS's documentation on Recursive CTEs and you should be able to get this running on your system.

Comment: Hi @JNevill, it worked. Thanks. Unfortunately, the table I'm using has more than 500 million rows. I was able to test it out with a sample of the data and worked perfectly. However, it's taking forever to run on the whole table. Do you know if there is some way to improve the performance of this query? Or if there is a way to use partition by in this case and just "order" the rows based on the hierarquy? Thanks again

Comment: The issue is that the hierarchy only exists in your data as a relational parent/child record. That is the correct way to store hierarchal data, but in your case, the the number of distinct hierarchies and nodes within are immense. I don't believe there will be any other way to sort by hierarchy without establishing a `path` or `depth` on which to sort, for each record.

Comment: If this is something that has to be done often, then maybe consider running this once, as painful as it is, and storing the depth in a new column. Then when new records come in adding to the product hierarchy, recalculate depth, after insert, for just the product that experienced the update, so you don't have to suffer the pain of a 500M record recursive request.

Comment: Thanks Jnevill. Great idea. I just did that. I ran the query once and stored the result in a new table. Then I created a CRON JOB to update the table daily, but only the rows with no "depth". In my case, the new rows will always go after the existing ones, so it was easier. Thanks again.

Comment: If there is the potential that an insert or update might stick a new id/parent in the middle of the hierarchy, then you could also rerun the hierarchy in that daily job for any group of distinct `product` records that have at least on record with a null depth. At any rate, I'm glad to hear this was helpful. It's an interesting problem to solve.